# Java Applet Hangs at starting up. Then turns into white screen

Tags: java, html, applet

I am hosting a VPS with a runescape private server on it. I have 2 main java files and a HTML file for the applet. I believe the problem starts in the HTML file, I could be wrong though. My reasoning behind this is because I launch the .jar file and it loads 100% and even logs into the runescape server. Here is the HTML and JAVA files:

http://stunnascape.servegame.com/stackoverflow/stackoverflow.zip
(the zip contains all java files) reply if u need more

If you need more files just ask, if you think its a totally different problem such as the cache download or something then just say so.. Because the only thing that changed is the line "Welcome to Teamtorva" into "Welcome to StunnaScape in the following files:  client.java (Line 11617) 
Gui.java (Line 224)
RSInterface.java (Line 4025)

Also Please check and verify that it is hanging up at the words "Starting up". Address is

Please click proceed (Sorry for not purchasing a SSL cert yet..)

https://stunnascape.servegame.com/

Comment: 404 when I click on any of the source files.